# Storing Auth Tokens in Azure Functions App

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function App that, when triggered, needs to call an API endpoint that requires OAuth2. My python code successfully calls the end point and authenticates just as i would expect. The API provides an 'Auth Token', 'Refresh Token' and a time that the auth token 'Expires On'.

The problem I am running into is: *Where can I store those values so that I don't have to request a new new token every single time my Azure Function App is called?*

When testing the code on my local machine I was storing them in a .env variable but it appears I cant write any files while its running on the Azure Function App. Is there an equivalent that is used for Azure? I currently have the values stored in Function App > Configuration Settings > Application Setting and it reads them fine but cant update as new values are acquired for expired tokens. I have tried to update the Application Setting variables using the following...

```
            try:
                os.environ["ACCESS_TOKEN"] = response.get("access_token")
                os.environ["REFRESH_TOKEN"] = response.get("refresh_token")
                os.environ["AUTH_EXPIRES_ON"] = str(expiresOn)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Couldnt write environmental config: ',e)
```

I don't actually want to store it in a file since thats not secure but I just need a value that will be secure and persist between different calls to the Azure Function App

I have a feeling I may be approaching the problem wrong... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Azure [KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/). You can retrieve the values and store secrets securely.

sample code in python:

```
    from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
    from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
    
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    
    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://<your_keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net", credential=credential)
    
    secret = secret_client.get_secret("AppSecret")
    
    # Set your API key as a secret in Azure Key Vault
secret_client.set_secret("<your-secret-name>", "<your-api-key>")
```

Comment: Great this worked like a charm!
To add another tip to anyone who gets here looking for answers on the topic....

You can use "Access Control (IAM)" to give permissions to your Key Vault for the Managed Identity of the Function App. The big improvement here is that you can simplify your code by using normal os.getenv(____) to access your Application Settings. 
If you do that, you then need to change the value of your "Application Setting" to a [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#reference-syntax) to the Key Vault.